# How to avoid deadlocks when calling an async method synchronously using HttpClient

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, httpclient

I have to do a POST call to a web api from a C# method. This method can't be an async where a task is returned. It has to be a synchronous method. The following is my code sample.The section marked as "Current code - working" is actually working. Since it might cause deadlocks as mentioned at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jpsanders/asp-net-do-not-use-task-result-in-main-context  I wanted to change it as described in the article. The method after the change is given under,"Modified code.". The problem is it returns a 400, Bad Request error.

```
//Current code - working
public HttpResponseMessage SendData(String jsonData)       
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

    HttpResponseMessage resp = client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

    if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //code to handle success
    }
    else
    {
        //code to handle error
    }
}

//Modified code. Returns 400, bad request
private static HttpResponseMessage SendData(string jsonData)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

    Task<HttpResponseMessage> callTask = Task.Run(() => client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")));
    callTask.Wait();

    HttpResponseMessage response = callTask.Result;
    return response;
}
```

Comment: What runtime are you targeting?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you would use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` to synchronously get the result of an asynchronous operation. For example

```
private static HttpResponseMessage SendData(string jsonData)
{
    // HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use. See 
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

    var response = client
                     .PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                     .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    return response;
}
```

But the better approach, of course, is to use async/await within your call stack.